# linear mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model

I would like to know how to fit a linear mixed model with `lme4`. The data is below:

```
Username Gender Trail    Age    Score   Age_C
 A       F      1        20     0.2     Young
 A       F      2        20     0.3     Young
 B       M      1        65     0.15    Old
 B       M      2        65     0.2     Old
```

It is a long data format.
For each user, they have 2 trails, and a score for each trail respectively.
I hope to know the differences in scores for 2 trials, which vary by gender and age.
And the data is pretty large, with ~200,000 pair users.

Should I build up a model like this?

```
lmer(Score~Age_C*Gender+(Trail|Username), data = data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your model formulation is incorrect. For `Trail` to appear in the random part as dependent on a random factor, then `Trail` should also appear as a fixed effect.
I would use a model like this:

```
glmmTMB::glmmTMB(Score~Age_C*Gender*Trail+(1|Username), data = data)
# (glmmTMB does what lme4 does and more)
```

This model tests the effect of `Age_C*Gender*Trail` on `Score` while allowing each `Username` set of observations to differ in their intercept, but not in their slope. In other words `Score` can differ across `Username` but every `Username` is assumed to respond to `Age_C*Gender*Trail` in the same way.

All this said, I have used mixed-effect models on-and-off for years but the more I use them, the more I learn. I suggest you to look more into them on formal sources, e.g. [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf), [here](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.htm), [here](https://www.bookdepository.com/Beginners-Guide-GLM-GLMM-with-R-Alain-F-Zuur/9780957174139), [here](https://tysonbarrett.com/Rstats/chapter-6-multilevel-modeling.html), [here](https://m-clark.github.io/mixed-models-with-R/random_intercepts.html).